# Loading Assmebly for same assembly name

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

In my application, I have two required assemblies in different app paths. These assemblies have different versions, publickeytoken but same assembly name. During the run time of the application, CLR throws the exception

> Could not load file or assembly** 'AssemblyName, Version=x.x.x.x,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxx' or one of its dependencies.
>   The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Please help resolve this issue.

Comment: Could you use an AppDomain for that Assembly?

Comment: Could these approaches help? [MSDN-Blog different versions of same dll](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/abhinaba/archive/2005/11/30/498278.aspx) and [MSDN AppDomain Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.appdomain(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Is there any other way because i have many dlls with both higher and lower versions? And i have a question why CLR throws me this above exception because except assembly friendly name other assembly parameters are different.

Comment: As of now i didnt try AppDomain. I ll try with AppDomain.